# error: 3 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found

Tags: flutter

I already declared my arguments but it says to me that 3 pos. arguments expected but 0 found. Error is at
**Article.fromJSON** part. Does anybody know why?

```
class Article {
  final String id;
  final String caption;
  final DateTime timestamp;

  Article(this.id, this.caption, this.timestamp, );


  factory Article.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) {
    return Article(
      id: jsonMap['id'] as String,
      caption: jsonMap['caption'] as String ,
      timestamp: jsonMap['timestamp'] as DateTime ,
      
    );
  }

  Map toMap() {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["id"] = id;
    map["caption"] = caption ;
    map["timestamp"] = timestamp ;
    return map;
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because your parameters aren't named,

Change

> Article(this.id, this.caption, this.timestamp, );

To

> Article({this.id, this.caption, this.timestamp, });